# One piece of unique armor still applies bonus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I'm wearing a full set of armor (like Dwarven) except for the helmet, which is a unique one (for exapmle the Visage of Mzund), will I still get the 25% bonus for wearing a full set of armor? I know I need a perk to get that bonus, I just want to know if I can have the bonus like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get the bonus for wearing a matching set, but you will get the bonus for wearing a full light/heavy armor set, if it meets that requisite.